# calculate 3 different amount with 2 value

Tags: javascript

Write a function addWithSurcharge that adds two amounts with surcharge. For each amount less than or equal to 10, the surcharge is 1. For each amount greater than 10 and less than or equal to 20, the surcharge is 2. For each amount greater than 20, the surcharge is 3. The call addWithSurcharge(10, 30) should return 44.

i find the answer but i think its to long 
i belive there is short answer fo this

```
    let cha = 1;
    let charge = 2;
    let surcharge = 3;

    function addWithSurcharge(x, y ){  
        let xe = xx(x);
        let ye = yy(y); 
        let result = xe + ye
        console.log(result); 
        }
    function xx(x){
        if(x <= 10){
            return x + cha
        } else if ( x > 10 && x <= 20){
            return x + charge
        } else return x + surcharge ;
    }
      function yy(y){
        if(y <= 10){
            return y + cha
        } else if ( y > 10 && y <= 20){
            return y + charge
        } else return y + surcharge ;
      }  

      addWithSurcharge(1, 1 ) //4
      addWithSurcharge(1, 20 ) //24
      addWithSurcharge(10, 30 ) // 44
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function addWithSurcharge(x, y) {
    let result = xx(x) + xx(y)
    console.log(result); 
}

function xx(x) {
    let cha = [1, 2, 3];
    let charge = x <= 10 ? cha[0] : (x <= 20 ? cha[1] : cha[2]);
    return x + charge;
}

addWithSurcharge(1, 1 ) //4
addWithSurcharge(1, 20 ) //24
addWithSurcharge(10, 30 ) // 44
```